# clear input boxes on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, input

I've a program which creates text input boxes dynamically. I want to clear the contents of the boxes on the click of clear button.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(CLId);
var myLength = elems.length;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
  if(elems[i].value != null && elems[i].value > 0){
    var el = elems[i];
  }
}
```

I use this to get the values of the boxes, but don't know how to make them empty....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **getElementsByTagName** (the class version is not cross-browser yet)
and **set the value to ""**, for the elements with the desired class.

```
var cname, elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for ( var i = elems.length; i--; ) {
    cname = elems[i].className;
    if ( cname && cname.indexOf(CLId) > -1 ) {
        // empty the input box
        elems[i].value = ""; 
    }
}
```

(or you can use a *reset* input box for the entire form)

Answer (score 4):

if it is in a form, you can simply use the `<input type="reset" value="clear"/>` tag (HTML). Otherwise you will want:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var l = elems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i){
  elems[i].value="";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the value:

```
el.value = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `elems[i]` in your loop is going to be a string, so you can test its length or its equivalent to the empty string (""). You can also set its value to "" to clear it.

```
elems[i].value = ""
```